# onClick inside of <Select

Tags: reactjs, onclick, jestjs

Trying to test the following click event  but simulate cant find any node.
I added an id as well in order to perform the test
I m not sure where the mistake is.
Using Jest and Enzyme

```
 </div>
 :  //console log wrapper stops here
  <div className='report-wrapper'>
 <div className='fields-item-wrapper span-two-col'>
   <label className='workflow-label' for=''> Contacts </label>
   <Select
    className={'field-input-select margin-right'}              
    value={this.state.Contact}
    onChange={(e) => {let val = e ? e.value : null; this.setState({Contact: e, Account: null, accountOptions: []}); this.getAccounts(e)}}
   inputId='testclickevent1'
   onClick={() => {this.setState({showRequired: false})} }
   options={this.state.contactOptions}
   isDisabled={loading}
   />
</div>
```

Here is what I have tried to so far:

```
beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<BrowserRouter><component

it("should check button click event - Select ", () => {
 baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
 wrapper.setProps({
 });
  wrapper.find('EditDatasubject').setState({
  Contact: {},
  Account: null,
  accountOptions: [],
  showRequired: false,
  });

 //console.log(wrapper.debug())
  wrapper.update() 
  wrapper.find('#testclickevent1').simulate("click", {value:'test'});
});
```

Comment: What library is Select from? Or is it a custom component? If custom please include in post.

Comment: import Select from 'react-select';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id isn't passing through from the component to the DOM. Try using `inputId` instead of `id`.

This thread has more info:
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/959

Comment: When  i try to wrapper.find(#  to find id , is it the same for inputId, because i still get the same error

Comment: when I add a console.log(wrapper.debug()) it does not show <select class